# Dealing with M occurrences among N

Tags: c++, arrays, algorithm

Question I've been given at the job interview. I was close to the solution but did not solve it unfortunately.

Assume we have a sequence that contains ***N*** numbers of type `long`. And we know for sure that among this sequence each number does occur exactly ***n*** times except for the one number that occurs exactly ***m*** times (*0* < ***m*** < ***n***). How do we find that number with *O(N)* operations and *O(1)* additional memory?

For the simplest case (when ***n*** = *2* and ***m*** = *1*) all that we should do is just to perform accumulative `xor` on every number in sequence. The result will be equal to the desired number. But i'm stuck while trying to deal with arbitrary ***m*** and ***n***.

I would appreciate an actual C++ solution.

---

EDIT: We know actual values of ***m*** and ***n*** a priori.

**Example.** We know that ***n*** = 3 and ***m*** = 2. The sequence (***N*** = *8*) is

```
5 11 5 2 11 5 2 11
```

And the right answer is *2* in this particular case because it occurs only twice.

Comment: How much time did they give you?

Comment: When you say "any number can occur exactly n times" do you mean each number _does_ occur exactly n times?

Comment: Do you know from which set the numbers are?

Comment: @ChaosPandion I had about fifteen minutes to think.

Comment: @Nabb Yes, we know them, but the solution must be generic.

Comment: @Armen No. From a range of `[0, 2^32)` actually cause as i've said they're all `long`.

Comment: Let me just say that this is a poor interview question.

Comment: @JoshD Yep, sorry, i should edit question a bit.

Comment: Can you define fantastical structures like an array the size of the domain of longs. Of most it be something representable.

Comment: @rerun That sounds very good. The solution is trivial now.

Comment: Is the requirement of `O(N)` for *worst case*? Or, a solution of `O(N)` for average case (or expected case) acceptable?

Comment: @ArunSaha Is the requirement of O(N) for worst case? - Yep.

Comment: @Peter G its a mapping problem

Comment: @rerun Make up your approach like an answer as i'm very curious what is it you are talking about.

Comment: @Steven Sudit: I'd have to argue that this could be a good question. The interviewer may ask this to see how they go about solving a difficult problem and not really care if they get the correct answer. Also, there is the possibility that the require someone with the skills to solve this kind of problem (unlikely, but still possible, especially in the embedded market).

Comment: @Grant: I will acknowledge that, for a very specific sort of job, this question is relevant. Unfortunately, this question tests more about math than coding, and being good at the former is neither required for nor indicative of being good at the latter. As someone who gives interviews, such a question would give me no information that would help me decide whether or not to hire, so I'd consider it poor for that reason.

Comment: @Steven Actually the job i was trying to attend requires strong but specific math knowledge as long as confident insight into effective programming techniques.

Comment: Then perhaps this generally bad question was appropriate in your case.

Comment: Wow, the programmers I usually get to interview can hardly solve the Fizzbuz test. There are really people out there who can solve a problem like that, when they're nervous and a couple of interviewers are watching them/breathing down their necks? Where can one find these people?

Comment: I wouldn't agree that maths are not relevant to a programmer, that said, this question is hit or miss. Whether or not your train of thought hit the right track is down to a lot of luck, I'm not sure that I would have made it in 15 minutes. If an interviewer want to test maths skills then something more conventional like basic statistics will probably prove more useful.

Comment: Fortunately i was left in private for some time they had decided to give me. But what has made me a great surprise is in fact they gave me yet two brainmelting questions along with this one. Furthermore the one was something really weird and i feel irresistible endeavor to ask SO community one more time.

Comment: Interviewing is a hard discipline, on one hand you would like questions around the level of the candidates, on the other hand you would also want to let the good candidates shine. These people clearly choose something over the top hard, and on top of that gave far too little time. Anyway, bring it on, it's a lot more fun than people asking how to do some simple task with jQuery.

Comment: @eBusiness: No, of course math is relevant, but it's just not more important than ability to program. For example, I had a co-worker with a PhD in Math from Columbia U. who just couldn't seem to grasp pointers or the need to free memory. He totally nailed recursion, though. :-)

Answer (score 30, accepted):

You do 64 sums, one for each bit, for each of the sums you calculate sum mod n, this calculation return m for each bit that should to be set in the result, and 0 for each bit that should not be set.

**Example:**
n = 3, m = 2. list = [5 11 5 2 11 5 2 11]

```
              5  11   5   2  11   5   2  11
sum of bit 0: 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 = 6   6 % 3 = 0
sum of bit 1: 0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 = 5   5 % 3 = 2
sum of bit 2: 1 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 = 3   3 % 3 = 0
sum of bit 3: 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 = 3   3 % 3 = 0
```

So only bit 1 is set, which means the result is 2.

**Optimizing implementation:**
*(Tricks and considerations that are also useful for real problems)*
It is worth noting that when iterating over an array, execution speed will to some extend be limited by memory access, if one need to perform multiple operations with each element it is usually fastest to perform them all on one element at a time, thus the processor only need to load each element from memory once. [Interesting blog post on memory and cache.](http://igoro.com/archive/gallery-of-processor-cache-effects/)

It is possible to sum multiple bits in a single integer, rather than applying 64 different bitmasks to get each bit on it's own one could for instance use only 4 bitmasks that each extract 16 bits with 3 bits of space between each, as long as no overflow occur a normal addition operation will work exactly as if dealing with 16 4-bit integers, thus this method will work for 15 numbers. After 15 numbers have been processed this way the results must be added to a storage capable of holding bigger integers (could be 8 64-bit integers each holding 8 8-bit integers, they must of course in turn be emptied into bigger integers etc.).
The result is that rather than for each value doing 64 bitmasks, 63 bitshifts and 64 additions one need only do 4 bitmasks, 3 bitshifts and 4 additions, plus for every 15 values 8 bitmasks, 4 bitshifts and 8 additions, plus for every 255 values 16 bitmasks, 8 bitshifts and 16 additions etc.

**Visualization:**
*(Summing 4x4-bit integers using 16-bit integers)*

```
1000 1000 1000 1000 +
1000 0000 0000 1000 +
0000 0000 0000 1000 +
1000 1000 0000 0000 +
1000 0000 1000 0000 +
0000 0000 1000 1000 =
0010 0100 1100 0010
```

The result is the same whether you consider this to be 4 columns of 4-bit integers or 1 column of 16-bit integers, this is only true as long as long the 4-bit integers do not overflow.

Comment: Wow, it is the **most easy, clear** and **elegant** solution! And it [works](http://ideone.com/9H2q2) perfectly.

Comment: Elegant. This can also be thought of as generalising xor, just with modulo m instead of modulo 2.

Comment: And _that's_ why they told him the exact size of integers. Great solution.

Comment: Good solution. Strictly speaking, this uses O(N log N) time and O(log N) words of memory (as with Nabb's). The standard assumption is that O(log n) bits of memory is O(1) words, and operations on these words each take O(1) time. I posted a solution below that uses O(1) words of memory, and has the same running time as this one.

Comment: @jonderry Strictly speaking it is O([int size] * N) time and O([int size]) memory. Of course one can cut a few bytes from memory use and get it down to O(1) by calculating the bit values one at a time, though that means iterating through the list once for each bit.

Comment: Yes, that's what my solution does. What I'm curious about is if you can get a true O(N) time solution that doesn't use much memory. Hashing gets you O(N) time, but requires O(N) memory.

Answer (score 9):

#### **edit)** Okay, this method isn't as sound as I initially thought. eBusiness's solution is much simpler and works correctly for cases such as n=4, m=2.

We can generalise the xor method to work with arbitrary **m** and **n**. We first need to pick a base **b** such that **gcd(n, b) = b**, and **gcd(m, b) < b**. As odd **n**/even **m** pairs satisfy this for base 2, the standard binary xor works for these pairs.

Firstly we define **(a^^n)** to mean **(a^a^...^a)** for **n a**'s, with generalised xor of base **b**. For example, with standard binary xor, **a^^2 = 0**.

We need to define our generalised xor. The properties we desire are basically the same as of addition (commutativity, associativity), and we need **a^^b = 0**. The obvious solution is **(x^y) = (x+y)%b** for each digit in the base **b** representation (convince yourself this works, and is the same as binary xor for base 2). Then, we simply apply this to all numbers in the sequence, and end up with **result = s^^(m%b)**, where s is the special number.
Lastly, we need to revert our 'xor'ed base **b** number to the expected number. We can simply compute **i^^(m%b)** for **i=0..b-1**, and then look up which value we have in **s** for each digit in **result**.

This algorithm is be O(N). For each number in the list, we have a constant number of operations to do, because we have at most 64 digits. Reverting at the end is at worst O(N) for large b. We can do this last step in constant space by computing **i^^(m%b)** for all **i** for each digit (again, we have a constant number of digits).

---

#### Example:

**n** = 3, **m** = 2. list = `[5 11 5 2 11 5 2 11]`

First we choose a base **b**. Obviously we have to choose base 3.

The xor table for reference:

```
  0|1|2
0|0|1|2
1|1|2|0
2|2|0|1
```

The computation:

```
  5     11      5      2     11      5      2     11
0^0=0. 0^1=1. 1^0=1. 1^0=1. 1^1=2. 2^0=2. 2^0=2. 2^1=0.
0^1=1. 1^0=1. 1^1=2. 2^0=2. 2^0=2. 2^1=0. 0^0=0. 0^0=0.
0^2=2. 2^2=1. 1^2=0. 0^2=2. 2^2=1. 1^2=0. 0^2=2. 2^2=1.

m % b = 2.
```

Thus we have s^^2 = [001]. We generate a table of i^^2 for each digit i, and then do a reverse lookup.

```
   i | 0 | 1 | 2 |
i^^2 | 0 | 2 | 1 |

0 -> 0
0 -> 0
1 -> 2
```

We lastly convert our result back into binary/decimal. [002] = 2.

Comment: It is the correct solution, but I don't think I would have been able to understand it had I not figured it myself before reading your reply.

Comment: That is really **great!** Finally at the interview i has discovered a thought that non-binary base representation might be very helpful. But i was totally confused after all.

Comment: However when tortures had came to the end interviewer told me that there exists a solution a lot easier as it misses non-binary-base-representation magic. This fact completely blows my mind.

Comment: This may have been what the interviewer was looking for, but this isn't strictly O(N) time and O(1) memory. The word size is logarithmic in N. Even though the standard transdichotomous model of computation gives us O(1) time operations on words of size O(lg N), it doesn't follow that we can keep one word for each bit and still consider this to be O(1) memory. Ditto on running time.

Comment: Sorry, it is not the same as my solution, looks a lot like it though, but this solution fails when n and m are not internally primary, try it with n=4 and m=2 and you will get an all-zeros result.

Comment: @jonderry: Since the values in the sequence are longs, we have at most `64 log(2) / log(b)` digits, so we have O(1) digits. Operations on each digit are O(1), so we have O(1) total.

Comment: OK, I don't understand the solution then. I thought you were essentially saying to keep a count of the number of occurrences of each bit, modulo some (possibly large) number. Doesn't this require roughly 64^2 memory, where 64 ~ log N?

Comment: BTW, I posted code for another solution below that uses only a constant number of additional words.

Answer (score 3):

You simplest case can be more general, you can use the same technique you described for an odd number **m** and even number **n**.

Comment: But the problem as stated can have m and n both even or both odd, or m even and n odd. You've only covered 1 of 4 possibilities.

Answer (score 3):

Here's a solution that has the same running time as eBusiness's (which I consider to actually be O(N log N)), but truly uses O(1) words of memory. It assumes m is not a multiple of n. It also assumes two helper functions that count the number of elements strictly above and below their arguments.

```
int divider = 0;

for (int i = 63; i >= 0; i--) {
  divider |= 1 << i;
  int a = countAbove(divider);
  int b = countBelow(divider);
  if (a % n == 0 && b % n == 0) return divider;
  else if (a % n == 0) divider ^= 1 << i;
}
```

Comment: It seems like your helper functions will make this O(N Log N) (off the top of my not-so-sharp head).

Comment: Exactly. The other solutions, including eBusiness', are O(N log N) as well. Unlike the other solutions, however, the memory used by this solution is only a constant number of words.

Answer (score 2):

- If you have a one to one hash on the set of integers from 0 to (N/n) + 1 then you can solve it by N iterations + N/n iterations with N memory useage.  However there isn't a one to one mapping
- If there is no constraint on memory it just must be constant you can define an array the size of the domain of longs that then you can solve the problem in 2N with constant gargantuan memory usage. For every x in N you simply Add to BIGARRY[x] then loop though BIGARRY looking for m.  Its terrible and non implementable but meets the requirements and most interview questions are thought experiments any way.

Answer (score 0):

If the list is sorted then this becomes quite simple in that you just need to examine each batch in turn to see if it is length m.

If the list is not sorted then I don't think it is possible with O(1) additional memory.

Comment: Interviewer swore it is possible. :)

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you can't do it using only O(1) additional space.

Here is my justification:  you are given:

- m
- n
- x_1 x_2 .. x_N

Since there are duplicates among the x_i values, let's define U as the set of unique values.  All the elements in U appear n times, and one of them appears m times in the x_i series.  Let us label the less often appearing element as u_0, and U_1 the set U - { u_0 }.

Let S be the the sum of all x_i.  S can be written as:

```
sum(x_i) = n * sum(U_1) + m * u_0 = n * sum(U) + (m - n) * u_0
```

Solving this problem is equivalent to finding the sum of the unique elements in a series, and you can't do that in O(1) additional space, because you need an array or a hash table with linked elements - the space is actually O(N)

Answer (score 0):

A soluation is some like the process to find the k-th order statistic

```
by dividing the sequence into 2 sub-seqs
(calculate the size of sub-seqs during the procedure)
while (sizeof(sub-seq) mod n != 0)
  do the same porcess on this sub-seq(dividing)
```

O(N) operations like finding the k-th order statistic.