# Estimating frequency of element of an array in O(n) time

Tags: arrays

I suppose the title might be a little misleading, but I couldn't think of a better one.
I have an array A[], all but one of whose elements occurs some number of times that is a multiple of 15, e.g. 2 occurs 30 times, 3 occurs 45 times. But one element occurs x times where x is not a multiple of 15. How do I print the number x. I'm looking for a linear solution without a hash-table.

Thanks.

Comment: Ahh, I was just going to say hash-table!  :)

Comment: @leppie if you want to have hashtable that will have guaranteed `O(1)` it will be `2^32` in size which is delusional. otherwise you can't hit guaranteed `O(n)`

Comment: Duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3963409/interview-question-dealing-with-m-occurrences-among-n

Answer (score 7, accepted):

There was similar question here, on StackOverflow, but i can't find it.

Lets use 3 instead of 15, because it will be easier and i think that it is completely equivalent. The sequence will be `4, 5, 4, 5, 3, 3, 4, 5`, in binary `100, 101, 100, 101, 11, 11, 100, 101`.

You can do the following: sum all values in least significant bit of numbers and take remainder over 3 (15 originally):

`bit1 = (0 + 1 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 1) % 3 = 5 % 3 = 2 != 0`

if it is `!= 0` then that bit is equal to 1 in number that we are trying to find. Now lets move to the next:

`bit2 = (0 + 0 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0) % 3 = 2 % 3 = 2 != 0`

`bit3 = (1 + 1 + 1 + 1 + 0 + 0 + 1 + 1) % 3 = 6 % 3 = 0 == 0`

So we have `bit3 == 0, bit2 != 0, bit1 != 0`, making `011`. Convert to decimal: `3`.

The space complexity is `O(1)` and time complexity is `O(n * BIT_LENGTH_OF_VARS)`, where `BIT_LENGTH_OF_VARS == 8` for byte, `BIT_LENGTH_OF_VARS == 32` for int, etc. So it can be large, but constants don't affect asymptotic behavior and `O(n * BIT_LENGTH_OF_VARS)` is really `O(n)`.

That's it!